# How to use select with awk in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, select, awk

I have to write a bash script for university, the text says:

> Write a bash script that allows root user, to get a list of all users
>   of the machine. Selecting a user, using select, will be required to
>   indicate a directory (indicate the absolute path). At this point in
>   the output will have be shown a list of all files folder owned by the
>   user, ranked in ascending order according to the size of file.

To check if the user is root i used:

```
if[ "$(id -u)" = 0 ]; then
```

To get the list of users of the machine I was thinking of using awk:

```
awk -F':' '{ print$1}' /etc/passwd
```

How can I use select with awk?
Is there another way without using awk?

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: You can use cut in much the same way, but I think your problem  with the select won't go away by that. The way **I** interret the statement is that you're supposed to present a list of users, read some input, and then respond to that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way to use awk in select statement, you need finish the rest for your homework (for example, sort the result)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

select user in $(awk -F ":" '{print $1}' /etc/passwd )
do
  read -p "input the absolute directory: " path
  find $path -type f -user "$user" -ls 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to test the UID by arithmetic (smarter!?) is :

```
if((UID==0)); then
    ...
else
    ...
fi
```

Check http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr